# Spring Servlet and Spring security filter chain Url Patterns

Tags: spring, spring-security, sitemesh

I'm having a lot of trouble debbuging those 404 messages on spring security's j_spring_security_check and j_spring_security_logout. I believe that there might be some conflict between SpringServlet Url-Pattern, springSecurityFilterChain Url-Pattern and/Or sitemesh.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And my ApplicationContext (including the spring-security parts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xpto.portal" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout"/> 
    </security:http>

    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />

    <security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
        <security:user name="john" password="21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:user name="jane" password="ee11cbb19052e40b07aac0ca060c23ee" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>


    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages">
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8">
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang">
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="pt">
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And a basic homepage Controller, which returns a view with sitemesh:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index()
    {
        return "home/index";
    }
}
```

This works for login. If I access localhost/portal I will be redirected to spring's default login page which will then redirect me to "/". Problem is this URL here:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/logout" />">Logout</a>
```

which generates a 404 and this error:

17:06:43,657 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-27) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Portal/logout] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springServlet'

This is the same either I change the logout-url or not.

I'm suspecting some incompatibility between the filters and spring servlet but I'm at loss.

can you help?

I'm using spring-security 4.0.1

Thank you!

Comment: Try remove : <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use a form to perform the logout. Something like this:

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

This is because spring-security's CSRF is enabled by default and the logout must be performed through POST with the CSRF token.

Answer (score 0):

change logout.
something like this.

```
<a href='<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />'>
```